# Interpretation of certain things in $Z_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers

$Z_7$ is the ring of integers *modulo* $7$.

I am beginner in ring theory and a question which says

> Find a reasonable interpretation for the expessions $1/2\ ,\ -2/3\ ,\ \sqrt{-3}\ \&\ -1/6$ in $Z_7$.

has got me stuck.

I think $\sqrt{-3}$ will be $\sqrt 4=2$ . But I am not being able to guess what to do with the division sign. Is it some analog of ***cosets*** ?

Comment: So you want $6x \equiv-1 \pmod{7}$ this says $6x \equiv 6\pmod{7}$ which says $x=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonable interpretation of these expressions is via equations. For instance:

- $-2/3$ is a solution to $3x \equiv -2 \bmod 7$
- $\sqrt{-3}$ is a solution to $x^2 \equiv -3 \bmod 7$

Comment: Just an added comment (not enough to write a full answer): the equation may have more than one solution, just like in the reals. One of these two equations has $2$ solutions.